# OSX Terminal Commands for find files with multiple criteria

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command, find

I've try to find files that are greater than 1GB and are of a special type (e.g. *.avi, *.mov, *.mpeg). What I've tried until now is

```
find . -name "*.mpeg" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mov" -size +1073741824
```

But this seems not to work as it shows files that are <1GB. I'm sure that can't be that complicated but I just don't see the solution :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find -cond1 -o -cond2 -cond3` will check for `cond1 OR (cond2 AND cond3)`, not `(cond1 OR cond2) AND cond3`. In math and programming, conjunction always has precedence over disjunction.

To make it work the way you want, just add your own grouping:

```
find . \( -name "*.mpeg" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mov" \) -size +1073741824
```

Comment: It seems not to work the way I hoped. Basically it should find all files within or below the current directory that meet the criteria "video" and file size >1GB.

Comment: The asterisks disappeared in the copypaste. Try again now.